# Multiple points of Gravity in d3.js

Tags: javascript, graphics, graph, physics, d3.js

Not sure if I'm using the right terminology so this question may already be answered somewhere on stackoverflow (if so, please let me know). Is there a way to designate multiple "gravity points" in a d3.js graph where the gravity point is one node with a fixed (x,y) value in each cluster? For example, I'm using the code from [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/2920551) to display clusters. The only difference in what my graphs will look like is that the nodes will have links to each other (possibly to nodes in other clusters as well). I want to make sure the other clusters overlap as little as possible and still show any links between each cluster.

I've tried force.gravity(0.1) with force.charge(-10). That seems to keep the clusters apart but the between-cluster distance continues to decrease as gravity increase because there is only one "gravity point" located in the middle of the graph by default.

Comment: You should add more Higgs boson particles :p

Comment: This is not Cluster Analysis: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis

Comment: This is only the visualization of a much larger cluster analysis I'm performing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way i  can think of is to add a node where you want to keep gravity and designate its charge with a large positive value , rest of the nodes should have a negative value charge. Hopefully they will attract towards each other. If you have found a better solution , please let me know.

Comment: I did something that was basically along these lines. I designated "static" nodes with fixed (x,y) values around a circle and then added "dynamic" nodes (changing [x,y] values) to the appropriate static node. With the version of d3.js I was using, you could only designate one point of gravity. d3.js may support multiple gravity points now.